# How could I say "the last" in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am learning ActionScript 3, and I have this code:

} else 
                {

```
                ourVod.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
                ourVod.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
```

I am making an object (A) stay inside another object (B) that is not the stage. Object A follows the mouse until it is outside the Object B, and right now it comes back to the centre. I would like to to change the valour "stage.stageWidth / 2" for something like "the last x and y value the mouse was", so the object stays in the same point as it was when the mouse left Object B.

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ignore your code, but something like that works (we imagine that your object B appears in the conditional test):

```
var oldX:Number;
var oldY:Number;

function enterFrameHandler(e:Event):void {
    if (mouseX > 100 && mouseX < 400 && mouseY < 350 && mouseY > 50) {
        oldX = A.x = mouseX;
        oldY = A.y = mouseY;
    } else {
        A.x = oldX;
        A.y = oldY;
    }
}

this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
```

Note: the coordinates of the object A are not necessarily at the limit of the object B. They are the last coordinates of the object A was when the mouse left object B.

Comment: Thanks helloflash, it worked perfectly!! Thanks a lot!!